# IDataReader out put parameter not giving correct value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am using Idatareader interface to read values from sql db. I have a out put parameter in my stored procedure to return no. of rows .

This out put parameter i am getting correct value in sql server. But when i tried to read this value in my code behind it is always returning 2.

After searching on net i found [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308621) , Still nothing changed after i implemented it.

```
             try{
               ObjDb.Open();
               ObjDb.CreateParameters(6);
               ObjDb.AddParameters(0, "@CategoryId", Category);
               ObjDb.AddParameters(1, "@StartDate", Date1);
               ObjDb.AddParameters(2, "@EndDate", Date2);
               ObjDb.AddParameters(3, "@PageIndex", 1);
               ObjDb.AddParameters(4, "@PageSize", 4);
               ObjDb.AddParameters(5, "@RecordCount", System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
               IDataReader objReader;
               objReader = ObjDb.ExecuteReader(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_filterevnts");                 
               while (objReader.Read())
               {
               .
               .
               .
               .

               }
         }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;

       }
       finally
       {
           ObjDb.Close();
           int count = Convert.ToInt32(ObjDb.dbParameters[5].Value);
           System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Count"] = count;
       }
       return Objlist;
```

*If i execute the Stored procedure in Sql management studio , it giving me correct out put value as @RecordCount 4*

```
Where as in code behind every time it is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an output parameter to return the record count and a `DataReader` to consume the records you should first process the reader, then you have to close it. Afterwards you can read the output parameter value.

```
while (objReader.Read())
{
   // ...
}
// close the DataReader.
objReader.Close();
// output parameter is now available
int count = Convert.ToInt32(ObjDb.dbParameters["@RecordCount"].Value);
// close the connection
```

Comment: I tried that also, still count is 2 ... ObjDb.dbParameters["@RecordCount"] is valid or Objdb.dbParameters[5] ...

Comment: Can you confirm that the recordcount is really 4, is it simply the number of records? Then you could use an `int` variable which you increase in the loop, if only to check it.

Comment: RecordCount is not the no. of records i am getting in reader, it is the total no. of records . Where as Datareader will get the sorted records from the total no . of records...And yes @RecordCount is giving me correct value in Sql server management studio